# Context não atualiza com o uso do UseState

Tags: javascript, contexto

Tenho um Context simples criado em um .jx :

UserContext.jx

```
import React from "react";
const UserContext = React.createContext();
export default UserContext;
```

No App.js chamo o context atribuindo um useState para uma variavel User que recebera varios parametros, nesse exemplo: nome, password, id, email, isLogged. Com valores iniciais setados.

App.js

```
export default function App() {

  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    email: 'email',
    password: 'pass',
    name: 'name',
    id: 'id',
    isLogged: true
  })

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      <AppRoutes isLogged = {user.isLogged} />
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Agora eu chamo ele dentro de algumas paginas, como teste para verificar se o context estava funcionando, chamei ele em duas pages: "Reports" e "Home" como mostrado abaixo:

Home.js e Reports.js

```
...
    const {user, setUser} = useContext(UserContext);
...
            <h5>{user.name}</h5>
            <h5>{user.email}</h5>
            <h5>{user.id}</h5>
            <h5>{user.isLogged? "Logged": "Not Logged"}</h5>
...
```

Resultado:

[image: Na Página Home]
[image: Na Página Reports]

Ou seja,
Está pegando tudo certo do context, agora será testar a alteração, criei um botão na pagina reports (como visto na foto), que quando clicado altera o valor de nome para : "Nome alterado".

```
<input type='button' onClick={() => {
  setUser({...user, name: 'Nome alterado'});
}}></input>
```

Quando clico no botão, o valor da página altera para "nome alterado", mas ao atualizar a pagina ou mudar de pagina, ele retorna para "name", como faço para que esse valor fique salvo no context ? (Eu entendo que em uma nova recompilação, em uma alteração do codigo e etc, os valores vao retornar para o default, mas acredito que não era para voltar para default so de mudar de pagina não ?)

[image: Depois que clicado o botao]
[image: Mudando de pagina]

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você está usando um roteador de uma "Single Page Application", este roteador irá te fornecer um componente de Link.

Quando você clica no link, ou manda o roteador trocar de página programaticamente (ex: `router.push()`), na verdade não está ocorrendo uma troca de página propriamente dita (ex: `window.location.href = "..."`).

O roteador irá substituir aquela seção da página e emitir um `history.push()` EMULANDO uma troca de página. Mas para o navegador na verdade a página nunca foi recarregada.

Se você não usar o componente de Link que o roteador fornecer, e ao invés disso colocar apenas um `href="..."`, a página toda vai recarregar e você vai sim perder o seu estado. Pois o estado está morando no script da página, que é zerado quando há troca de página ou recarregamento.

Caso você queira persistir valores entre carregamentos, você terá que fazer uso de uma das APIs de persistência do navegador, as quais são:

- Localstorage, IndexedDB, cookies.

... e vai ter que escrever código para em cada inicialização de página, ler do localstorage pra popular o estado do javascript. E também escrever código pra ler do JS pra salvar na persistência do navegador.